# How to get area, road with information like jam from HERE Api?

Tags: here-api

I am trying to get traffic flow information from HERE Api. But the Flow api which gives real time data.The api link is 
https://traffic.ls.hereapi.com/traffic/6.3/flow.xml

I want statistics of traffic jam from here api. Is there any HERE api to get statistics or pattern of traffic. Please help me out. 
I find that there is another api i.e Traffic flow availability, which needs
'profile' as parameter. can anyone please explain this term ?

Comment: can you help me please https://stackoverflow.com/users/12360213/shruti-kuber

Answer (score 0):

You can check Traffic flow API end point to achieve your task:

> Profile defines such attributes as geographic coverage (TMC tables
>   available for use) and custom color mapping for tile overlays

```
https://traffic.ls.hereapi.com/traffic/6.0/flowavailability.json?apiKey={}
```

for more detail please check [this](https://developer.here.com/documentation/traffic/dev_guide/topics_v6.1/resource-parameters-flow.html).

Comment: actually i want statistics of trafiic jam for each road , given co-ordinate .I am not looking realtime data.   Can I use this api    https://traffic.ls.hereapi.com/traffic/6.0/flowavailability.json?apiKey={}   . If my requirement is solved by using that Api . Then     can you explain what the profile parameter is in details . Or how to calculate profile value ??

Comment: You should probably go with this then- https://traffic.ls.hereapi.com/traffic/6.1/flow.json?apiKey=&prox=51.5072,-0.1275,100

Comment: But the flow api you are specifying it is only for real time traffic flow. But I want statistics of trafffic given the coordinate https://stackoverflow.com/users/3505695/here-developer-support